# How do I transition from a classical education to a jazz education in piano and theory?

Tags: piano, jazz, classical-music, transition

I’ve been learning piano theory from a classical standpoint on-and-off for about 8 years of my life, and I feel as though I haven’t gotten anywhere.

I compose and improvise in my spare time, but I have little to no education and I feel as though I play the same things over and over again, due to the fact that I know nothing of chord progressions and/or improvisational techniques.

I have an appointment with a jazz teacher tomorrow, but I’d very much appreciate any tips and such on how to transition and grow, please! I’d still like to pursue composing and improvisational piano, thanks!

Comment: It's nearly a year on now.  How did the lessons go?  What would YOU now tell us are the differences between classical and jazz?

Answer (score 3):

The first tip I can offer is to listen to the teacher you're seeing tomorrow!

But remember, theory is a set of descriptions, not a set of instructions.  Work from the music. Listen, imitate, then (if you like) analyse.

Comment: The best way to learn jazz is to listen, apply, then analyze. Once you can analyze while listening, you've already done a big step. +1